# Date filter from Multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to return date filtered result from 3 collections using the code below:

```
app.post('/api/v1/transaction/filter/date', async  (req, res)   => {

    await Transaction.find({date: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }},  (err, transactions) =>{
        transactions.map(transaction => {
            TransactionDetail.find({transactionId: transaction._id})
                .then(transactionDetails => {
                    Payment.find({transactionId: transaction._id})
                        .then(payments => {
                            transactionObject.push({
                                id: transaction._id,                                    
                                totalPayment: transaction.totalPayment,                                  
                                date: new Date(transaction.date).getTime(),
                                transactionDetails: transactionDetails,
                                payments: payments
                            });
                        })
        });
    })
```

When I run the above code, it returns [] but when I run same code adding Line 1 and Line 2 as seen below,

```
    app.post('/api/v1/transaction/filter/date', verifyToken,  async  (req, res)   => {
    await Transaction.find({date: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }},  (err, transactions) =>{
        transactions.map(transaction => {
            TransactionDetail.find({transactionId: transaction._id})
                .then(transactionDetails => {
                    Payment.find({transactionId: transaction._id})
                        .then(payments => {
                            transactionObject.push({
                                id: transaction._id,                                   
                                totalPayment: transaction.totalPayment,                                  
                                date: new Date(transaction.date).getTime(),
                                transactionDetails: transactionDetails,
                                payments: payments
                            });       
                })
        });
    })

    //Added Line 1
    await TransactionDetail.find({},  (err, transactionDetails) =>{})

    //Added Line 2
    await Payment.find({},  (err, payments) =>{})
    })
```

it returns the expected result:

```
  {
id: 5f4d356c2f0e03049893273b,
totalPayment: 0,
date: 1597167420000,
transactionDetails: [ [Object] ],
payments: [] 
}
```

Please kindly explain what I'm doing wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After much research on this, I couldn't find any answer so i used the code below to resolve the issue

```
{
        Transaction.aggregate([
            {
                $match:
                        {
                            date: {$gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }
                        }
            },
            {
                $set:
                        {
                            _id:{ $toString:"$_id"} //Convert the trasaction._id to string
                        }
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                        {
                            from: "transactiondetails",
                            localField: "_id", //transaction._id is now a string
                            foreignField: "transactionId",
                            as: "transactionDetails"
                        }
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                        {
                            from: "payments",
                            localField: "_id",
                            foreignField: "transactionId",
                            as: "payments"
                        }
            },
            
        ], (err, transactions) => {
            transactions.map(transaction => {
                transactionObject.push({
                    id: transaction._id,
                    totalPayment: transaction.totalPayment,
                    date: new Date(transaction.date).getTime(),
                    transactionDetails: transaction.transactionDetails,
                    payments: transaction.payments,
                });
            });
            res.json({
                transactions: transactionObject,
                code: 100
            });
        });
    }
```